# SlickGrid frozen-column example source code

Tags: slickgrid

Where can I find the source code for http://jlynch7.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-frozen-columns.html? I could not find it in the examples folder in the source code.

Comment: you're probably looking in the wrong branch. look in the 2.0-frozenRowsAndColumns branch https://github.com/JLynch7/SlickGrid/tree/2.0-frozenRowsAndColumns/examples

Comment: You are right, I was looking at the master branch. This is a great addition to SlickGrid. Do you know if this feature will be offered as a pull request to the slickgrid master repository?

Comment: There has been a lot of discussion around this (https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/search?q=frozen+columns&ref=cmdform&type=Issues), but I would doubt that frozen column support would be included in the main SlickGrid repo anytime soon. Best to stick with jlynch7's implementation for now if that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. If you could add your earlier comment as an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frozen columns is part of the JLynch7/SlickGrid/2.0-frozenRowsAndColumns branch

https://github.com/JLynch7/SlickGrid/tree/2.0-frozenRowsAndColumns/examples